# Facebook ads objective, app install vs traffic

Tags: facebook, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I don't think there's a way to collect install data (such as utm params) when you use facebook `install app` objectives.
You can only see what facebook provides you on their dashboard

(I wonder why facebook refuses to give customers a power to collect data.)

You can instead use `traffic` objective. Then you can use any url you want and forward the user to app install (by means of firebase dynamic link or similar)

1. Has anyone used facebook `traffic` over `install ads` objective for this reason? and how was the result? (did the install rate drop significantly?)
2. Is it possible to tag `app install ads`? (We want to know how many installs are from facebook ads in our internal system, usually we would add `utm_source=facebook` and count the installs with the tag.
   ([How facebook measure app installs - Android/IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28313356/how-facebook-measure-app-installs-android-ios) says it's not possible, that's what I keep finding whenever I look into this, but not sure if things changed)

Comment: Did you ever find a way to do this, or tried to use another ad type to be able to do it? What where the results? Thank you.

Comment: No, there's no way to do this